# Can't call all methods from different Form

Tags: c#, winforms, methods

I have a problem with calling method from another class. `Form1.cs` contains:

```
public void RefreshTreeview()
{
    MessageBox.Show("test");
    this.treeView1.Nodes.Clear();
    this.textBox10.Text = "test";
}
```

When I'm trying to call this method from another class "Form2.cs":

```
public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 Obj = new Form1();

    Obj.RefreshTreeview();
    this.Close();
}
```

I'm receiving only message box with text. `Treeview` doesn't "clear" and `textBox10` didn't dipslay "test". However when i'm trying to call the same method from method inside `Form1` all elements were executed:

```
private void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RefreshTreeview();
}
```

Of course both classes are public. Please help.
Regards

Comment: You are creating a NEW instance of Form1. This instance has its own treeview and textbox. The instance of Form1 that you are looking at is untouched by your code. Because you are not calling Obj.Show then this instance cannot show its own textbox where you have written the word "Test". Instead, when you are calling the method from the first Form1 instance everything works as expected because the method works on the treeview and textbox owned by the first instance

Comment: This is maybe a duplicate. Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1157791/3165552)

Comment: get form1 instance in form2 ctor,ofcourse you must have a private field in form2 of type form1 and in ctor assing it,then in you button2 click handler use that field.Or simply in your button2 click handler place - Form1 f = (Form1)Application.OpenForms["Form1"];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a new instance of the `Form1` and then clear it you have to use `Show()` method. E.g.:

```
public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    Form1 f = new Form1();
    f.RefreshTreeview();
    f.Show();
}
```

But I assume your aim is to clear already existing form. Easiest way is to inform the `Form2` who is its owner. Then you can access the owner from the `Form2`.
So in the method you use to invoke `Form2` from `Form1`, instead of using `Show()` method use `Show(this)` - this way you pass current instance as the owner of the new dialog.

Code in `Form1`, where you invoke `Form2`:

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
f2.Show(this);            // Current window is now the owner of the Form2
```

And now on the `Form2` you can do your thing with accessing `Form1`, removing `Nodes` and setting text:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.Owner == null) return; // Sanity check if there is no owner.
    Form1 f = (Form1)this.Owner;    // Get the current instance of the owner.
    f.RefreshTreeview();            
    f.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to retrieve the same `Form1` instance which is probably the one you are actually seeing on the screen.

```
public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 Obj = // retrieve instead of create a new one

    Obj.RefreshTreeview();
    this.Close();
}
```

To retrieve the `Form1` instance there are multiple ways please leave a comment if required.